# SQL Server 2008 Bug with Fulltext Creation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, fulltext-index

I have SQL Server 2008 (Version 10.0.2531).

The following annoying bug? happens, and maybe someone has a workaround: When I create a computed column which also combines values from a scalar valued function, and then add it to the fulltext index via the wizard, everything works fine. The fulltext index correctly picks up on the column and I can search and return results as expected.

If I now try to change anything on table, or any FK-connected table - for example, add another field - it won't accept the change and cancel out of the save dialog saying that my computed column can't be fulltext indexed.

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the details of your function I can't be sure but I'd guess that the function was created with schemabinding.

Comment: Yes it is with schemabinding as the UDF otherwise wouldn't be allowed in the computed column.

Comment: Then I think that explains why you're not allowed to alter the tables.